# Can't locate Geo/Gpx.pm in @INC apache mac

Tags: perl, apache, macports, osx-mavericks, gpx

Though there are many queries flowing around asking the same question. But here the error is thrown by apache instead of Perl.
I am trying to create an XML Response for the client on Mac OS X Mavericks and have written the perl script as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT                                                                                                                                                                  
use lib '/opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.1/Geo';
use strict;
use CGI;
use Geo::Gpx;

open (FH, "/tmp/temp/file.txt") or print ("Unable to Open File");

my $gpx = Geo::Gpx->new;
my $cgi = CGI->new;
print $cgi->header(-type=>"text/gpx",-status=>"200 OK");

my $lon;
my @arr = <FH>;

foreach(@arr){
my %waypoints;
my $var = $_;
my @lat = split(/\s+/,$var);
#@waypoints=split(/\s+/,$_);                                                                                                                                                     
$waypoints{$lat[0]}=$lat[1];
$waypoints{$lat[2]}=$lat[3];
$gpx->add_waypoint(\%waypoints);
}

my $xml = $gpx->xml;
print $xml;
open FILE, ">/tmp/temp/xmlfile.xml" or die $!;
print FILE $xml;
close (FILE);
close(FH);
```

For the apache to find the actual path of the Gpx.pm, I have used 'use lib' to show it the real path of the file.
Although this script is working perfectly on command line, my apache server is throwing the following error:

```
[Tue Nov 26 18:34:51 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Can't locate Geo/Gpx.pm in @INC 
(@INC contains: /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.1/Geo /Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level 
/Library/Perl/5.16 /Network/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.16 
/Library/Perl/Updates/5.16.2 /System/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.16 
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16 .) at /Users/Rachit/Sites/temp.pl line 7.
[Tue Nov 26 18:34:51 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /Users/Rachit/Sites/temp.pl line 7.
```

I have used macports and have found searching through the Web that Mavericks has got perl 5.16 preinstalled. So apache may be using that and perl is using the macport installed libraries. 
On checking the paths mentioned by apache error_log file as I posted above, I have copied Gpx.pm in one of the libraries installed in Geo Folder but still not getting it resolved.
On running 'which perl' The result

```
/opt/local/bin/perl
```

And 'which cpan' is giving

```
/opt/local/bin/cpan
```

Kindly fix this issue as I am not able to move forward because of this. And I am not so familiar with apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.1/Geo` should be `/opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.1/` as it will append the complete module name (replacing `::` with `/`) to each path to find the files.

Comment: Could you please Answer one more issue. Instead of sending the response at the background, my browser is printing the complete xml file. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: @001011Idreamincode Add the following to the header() call: `-Content_Disposition => "attachment; filename=download.gpx"`. And maybe use `application/xml` instead of `text/gpx`.